# PHP script not working for meta description? Update for twitter cards

Tags: php, meta-tags

I'm just trying to make this random script to make meta, open graph and twitter cards eisier together.

This is my PHP Code

```
<?PHP
    $Title = "This is the Open Grah script";
    $Description = "This is the one and only Description, or better yeh the first 150 charecters of the main content on your page. What ever you feel like really!";

     echo "<html>
            <head>
             <title> $Title </title>";
     echo '<meta name="description" content=" ';
     echo '$Description';
     echo '" />';
?>
```

But this what happens in the source code when in the browser:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> This is the Open Grah script </title><meta name="description" content=" $Description" />
```

So basically it's not printing the `$Description` variable.

**Update**

```
<?PHP
    $Title = "This is the Open Grah script";
    $Description = "This is the one and only Description, or better yeh the first 150 charecters of the main content on your page. What ever you feel like really!";
    $Twitter = "@obama";

     echo "<html>
            <head>
             <title> $Title </title>";
     echo '<meta name="description" content=" ';
     echo $Description;
     echo '" />';

     echo "<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />";  
     echo '<meta name="twitter:site" content"';
     echo $Twitter
     echo '"/>';
     echo '<meta name="twitter:title" content"';
     echo $Title;
     echo '" />';
     echo '<meta name="twitter:description" content" ';
     echo $Description;
     echo '" />';

    ?>
```

So it worked at first but it's not working now, don't really see the error.

Comment: use `echo $Description;`. remove single quote.

Comment: Anybody got any idead what might be wrong with it now??

Comment: I tried using the errorr reporting function, no luck either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

print a php variable with single quote **'$Description'** it assume as string not a variable so you should do wrap it in double quotes **"$Description"**.

Change

`echo '$Description';`

to

```
echo "$Description";
```

Or simple echo the variable

```
echo $Description;
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using like this  `echo '$Description';` use like this `echo $Description;`

Answer (score 1):

In single quotes in PHP the dollar sign isn't interpretted, you double-quotes, or nothing:

```
echo $Description;
```

OR

```
echo "$Description";
```